# Using jQuery to animate an object with properties already defined as "!important"

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm using jQuery .show() to animate adding extra DOM elements to a page, and when each is added, I would like the elements below to gracefully slide down in the same way.

Unfortunately, the other elements have their positions defined with CSS `!important` flags, meaning they cannot be moved by the sliding animation without the animation itself also setting the `!important` flag at every animation step. Is there any way of doing this?

Unfortunately, it is completely technically impossible for me to modify the source HTML or linked CSS styles.

Comment: Thought any changes made after loading the webpage would overwrite the actual style definitions.

Comment: styles can be overrided, but not actually removed. In this case, overriding doesn't actually help, as the only way to override is by specifying another !important rule, which leaves me with the same animation problems.

Comment: Think of styles as the rules of the game. Some rules are more important than other (har har), but if the coach tells a player to foul an opponent it doesn't really matter what the rule-book says...  Javascript changes the actual item properties, it doesn't give a rat's ass about the "rules" ;)

Comment: I think the only thing you can do is to hack the jQuery source code to add `!important` at every step of the animation. Nothing in the existing `animate()` method is designed to compensate for this.

Comment: @Herald_MJ Did you ever find a solution that worked for you? I made a suggestion below that should allow you to work around the restriction of unmodifiable HTML/CSS without anything so drastic as hacking jQuery or overwriting the stylesheet.

Comment: David - thanks for the suggestion, although it is quite a good one, I'm afraid it won't work in my particular situation. Nevertheless, I think aside from hacking the jQuery source, your solution is the one most likely to work for others with similar problems to mine, so I'm going to mark your answer as the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though your div has a style that is defined as !important, children of that div should still be able to override that style. In light of this, what if you add a new element (using jQuery) first and then apply the styles to that new element instead? Like so:

```
$("#something").wrapInner("<span class='test' />").children(".test").animate({
    fontSize: "3em"
  }, 1500 );
```

This way you do not have to modify the original HTML/CSS or the jQuery framework itself and in most cases you can still achieve the desired effect.

Example jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rVzhf/4/

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles override `!important`, so use `$(element).css('top','10px')` or remove the class names from the elements that contain `!important`.

Comment: I dont think inline styles overwrite !important tags, because he wouldn't have the problem in the first place if they did.

Comment: inline styles only override `!important` if also specified as `!important`. Doing so does not change my animation problem.

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/rVzhf/1/

Comment: You can control the stylesheet directly and perhaps remove the !important statements. This plugin may help: http://flesler.webs.com/jQuery.Rule/

Comment: or this one: http://www.burnbright.co.nz/resources/globalstylesheet-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score -3):

I do think that by calling those attributes "!important" you just screwed yourself. Really.

!important attributes will go over anything that is not !important... Jquery adds styles as inline, the highest possible before !important; and I don't think you can ask jquery to add an important attribute.

Solution: Rework your CSS to not use the !important. Way to do it would be to abuse the score system. In short, the longer the selector, the more important it is, without using the !important tag. !important is for exceptions.

Another way, and I'm not sure this will work, is to put your !important css as inline. It should get remplaced by whatever value Jquery puts in.

Comment: "Unfortunately, it is completely technically impossible for [OP] to modify the source HTML or linked CSS styles."

Comment: Then reffer to other answer -> You have to fight fire with fire, or !important with !important.

Comment: I didn't define the original attributes as `!important`, I have no control over them.

I'm willing to "fight fire with fire" by specifying more rules as `!important`, I'm just specifically looking for a way to do it with jQuery animations.