# JQuery unable to animate div after "forwards" css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

See example 
http://jsfiddle.net/nxsv5dgw/

Div appears on stage, a "forwards" animation occurs on it, JQuery can apparently no longer "animate" the properties that were animated.

In the example, a css animation plays on the width of a box. OnClick, a JQuery animation tries to shrink the width and height of the box, but only the height is changed. Here's the code.

```
$(".a").click(function(e) {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "-=100px", // doesn't work after CSS animation
    height: "-=100px",
  }, 400); 
})

.a {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  height:500px;
  width:600px;
  animation: anim 0.4s forwards 1s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {width:600px;}
  100% {width:500px;}
}
```

Is there any way to circumvent this? I'd rather avoid doing all animations in JQuery if possible.

Comment: You don't want to use jQuery, but you're already using it?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations `. Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important rules`

Comment: @ericbelldesigns Correct, I want to minimise the use of JQuery as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only tested for Firefox, but working - I've adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv15ptay/) adding

```
$(this).css({
    "width": $(this).width(),
    "animation": "none"
});
```

to the click-function. This sets the width to the actual width and overrides the animation, but I think there could be a better solution as it looks like a hack.

Update - also working for Safari and IE.

Comment: Doesn't it conflict with css animation of element if element gets clicked on before the css animation is completed?

Comment: @GauravKalyan Thanks for mentioning. Yes, it does, and maybe this is not a minor detail that can be overlooked (though for the example animation you have to click very fast). Therefore I wrote that there could be a cleaner solution, and adding the click event _after_ the animation ended (like you did in your answer) seems for me to be the cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can set the width to `500px` after the animation is complete so that DOM element knows that DIV has width `500px` and remove the css animation from Element.

```
$(".a").on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function () {
    $(this).width(500);
    $(this).css({
            "animation": "none"
        });
    $(".a").click(function (e) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: "-=100px",
            height: "-=100px",
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

**Basic Idea:** To avoid conflicting between CSS animation and jQuery animation one should call the jQuery animation only when CSS animation is completed by using `animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd` event and by undoing the rules overriden by CSS animation and removing animation from the element.

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nxsv5dgw/16/)**

Comment: Just a note: would be better to use `.on()` than `.bind()`. The latter has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, this happens by using `forward` in animation.

From the [CSS Animations Working Draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations)

> CSS Animations affect computed property values. During the execution of an animation, the computed value for a property is controlled by the animation. This overrides the value specified in the normal styling system. Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important rules.

and [Animation Duration](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation-duration)

> […] and an animation that fills forwards will retain the value specified at the 100% keyframe, even if the animation was instantaneous. Also, animation events are still fired.

So, it cannot be overriden by default, except for !important rules. But this [cannot be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300617/using-jquery-to-animate-an-object-with-properties-already-defined-as-important) using `jQuery.animate()`

> I'd rather avoid doing all animations in JQuery if possible.

I guess that you can't.

You could use a jQuery solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.a').delay(1000).animate({
    width: "-=100px"    
  }, 400);
  
});

$(".a").click(function(e) {
  $(this).animate({
    width: "-=100px", // doesn't work after CSS animation
    height: "-=100px",
  }, 400); 
})
```

```css
.a {
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  height:500px;
  width:600px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an option, as the effect is slightly different then what you are aiming for, but I just wanted to put it out there as an alternative.

The problem is clearly caused by the fact that (http://w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animations)

> Animations override all normal rules, but are overriden by !important
>   rules

Therefore you could try to **animate the `scale` transform** in stead. This way you are not altering the properties that have been set trough the animation. jQuery does not support it out of the box, but this plugin adds the functionality: https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit.

This also has the huge added advantage of being **much better for performance** then animating your width an height, as very well explained here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

The drawback of this method is that the **contents of your div is scaled down as well**, which may not be the desired effect.

I've set up a demo to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/nxsv5dgw/13/

And the code:

```
$(".a").click(function (e) {
    $(this).transition({
        scale: '-=0.1'
    }, 4000);
});
```